# How do I perform an additional action only on the first iteration of a loop?

Tags: php, loops

I know how to do this... I'll give example code below.  But I can't shake the feeling that there's a clever way to accomplish what I want to do without using a variable like `$isfirstloop`.

```
$isfirstloop = true;
foreach($arrayname as $value) {
 if ($isfirstloop) {
  dosomethingspecial();
  $isfirstloop = false;
 }
 dosomething();
}
```

Is there any way to execute `dosomethingspecial()` only on the first loop, while executing `dosomething()` on every loop, without introducing a variable like `$isfirstloop`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach ($arr as $i => $val)
{
  if ($i == 0) { doSomethingSpecial(); } // Only happens once.
  doSomething(); // Happens every time.
}
```

Comment: +1 Exactly how i'd apprach it, of course if it's an associative array this wouldnt work, as you'd get the key instead of the index.

Comment: You'd have to assume the array is numbered with the first key being zero. Consider an array with unset 0 element.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  It seems so simple, yet I've never come up with it.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6):

Forgive me if I'm missing something, but why not just do the thing you want before the loop?

```
dosomethingspecial();
foreach($arrayname as $value) {
 dosomething();
}
```

Comment: And if you need the first element for doSomethingSpecial() you can use e.g. reset($arrayname) (if the array may be reset before the loop)

Comment: dosomethingspecial() will always be invoked, no matter whether the $arrayname array is populated with elements or not, I would assume he at least wants this to be invoked if its populated at least with one element.

Comment: Yes, if you take VolkerK's comment into account.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... You can `reset` the array and then see if you're on the first key:

```
reset($a); foreach($a as $k => $v) {
    if(key($a)==$k) doIt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = count( $arr );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
    if ( $i == 0 ) { dosomethingspecial(); }
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Great for associated arrays or arrays with non-contiguous numbering.

Answer (score 0):

```
$elem = reset($arrayname);
dosomethingspecial();
while( ($elem = next($arrayname)) !== FALSE ) {
  dosomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your not gaining any performance from the alternative methods. Your method is just fine.